# can not print whole record with use of for each loop

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

my template file is like this i am try to print fetch records from data base but problem is my select query working properly but in front i cant print whole records which i get in result it is only print first record
where is my mistake can anybody help me for this

```
    <table id="example" class="cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Particular</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Rate</td>
        <td>Diff</td>
        <td>Diff Amount</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>K.G.</td>
        <td>Total Amount</td>
        <td>Javak Date</td>
        <td>Javak Fine</td>
        <td>Javak Amount</td>
        <td>Aavak Date</td>
        <td>Aavak Fine</td>
        <td>Aavak Amount</td>
      </tr>
      {foreach from=$clientDetail item=onerow}
       <input type="hidden" name="clientId" value="{$onerow.clientId}">
         <td><a href="client.php?clientId={$onerow.clientId}"><img src="img/edit.png"></a></td>
         <td>{$onerow.particular}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.cDate}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.rate}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.diff}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.diffAmt}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.total}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.kg}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.totalAmt}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.javkDate}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.javkFine}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.javakAmt}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.avakDate}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.avakFine}</td>
         <td>{$onerow.avakAmt}</td>
      </tr>
      {/foreach}
    </table>
    </form>
    {/block}
```

this is my select query

```
<?php
include("include/config.inc.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['s_activId']))
{
  $_SESSION['s_urlRedirectDir'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  header("Location:checkLogin.php");
}
else
{
    $partyId = isset($_REQUEST['partyId']) ? $_REQUEST['partyId'] : 0;

    $k = 0;
    $clientDetail = array();
    $selectClient = "SELECT * FROM client
                     WHERE partyId = ".$partyId;
    $selectClientRes = mysql_query($selectClient);
    while($clientRow = mysql_fetch_array($selectClientRes))
    {
      $clientDetail[$k]['clientId']     = $clientRow['clientId'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['particular']   = $clientRow['particular'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['cliTransType'] = $clientRow['cliTransType'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['cDate']        = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($clientRow['cDate']));
      $clientDetail[$k]['rate']         = $clientRow['rate'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['diff']         = $clientRow['diff'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['diffAmt']      = $clientRow['diffAmt'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['total']        = $clientRow['total'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['kg']           = $clientRow['kg'];
      $clientDetail[$k]['totalAmt']     = $clientRow['totalAmt'];


      $selectCr = "SELECT rojmelDate AS javkDate,fine AS javkFine,amount AS javakAmt 
                        FROM rojmel
                   WHERE rojTransType = 'J'
                  AND partyId = ".$partyId;
      $selectCrRes = mysql_query($selectCr);
      while($clientRow = mysql_fetch_array($selectCrRes))
      {
        $clientDetail[$k]['javkDate'] = $clientRow['javkDate'];                 
        $clientDetail[$k]['javkFine'] = $clientRow['javkFine'];                 
        $clientDetail[$k]['javakAmt'] = $clientRow['javakAmt'];                 

      } 

      $selectCr = "SELECT rojmelDate AS avakDate,fine AS avakFine,amount AS avakAmt 
                        FROM rojmel
                   WHERE rojTransType = 'A'
                  AND partyId = ".$partyId;
      $selectCrRes = mysql_query($selectCr);
      while($clientRow = mysql_fetch_array($selectCrRes))
      {
        $clientDetail[$k]['avakDate'] = $clientRow['avakDate'];                 
        $clientDetail[$k]['avakFine'] = $clientRow['avakFine'];                 
        $clientDetail[$k]['avakAmt']  = $clientRow['avakAmt'];                 

      } 
     $k++;
    } 

    $z=0;
    $clientArray = array();
    $selectClient = "SELECT partyId,partyName
                       FROM party
                    WHERE partyType = 'C'";
    $selectClientRes = mysql_query($selectClient);
    while($clientRow = mysql_fetch_array($selectClientRes))
    {
      $clientArray['partyId'][$z]   = $clientRow['partyId'];
      $clientArray['partyName'][$z] = $clientRow['partyName'];
      $z++;
    }

    $selectAmount = "SELECT SUM(kg) AS jKg,SUM(totalAmt) AS jtotalAmt
                       FROM client
                      WHERE cliTransType = 'J'
                AND partyId = ".$partyId;
    $selectAmountRes = mysql_query($selectAmount);
    if($jrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectAmountRes))
    {
      $jKg          = $jrow['jKg'];
      $jtotalAmt    = $jrow['jtotalAmt'];

    }

    $selectAavkAmount = "SELECT SUM(kg) AS aKg,SUM(totalAmt) AS atotalAmt
                       FROM client
                      WHERE cliTransType = 'A'
                AND partyId = ".$partyId;
    $selectAavkAmountRes = mysql_query($selectAavkAmount);
    if($arow = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectAavkAmountRes))
    {
      $aKg          = $arow['aKg'];
      $atotalAmt    = $arow['atotalAmt'];  
    }

    $finalKg     = $aKg - $jKg;
    $finalAmount = $atotalAmt - $jtotalAmt;


    include("./bottom.php");
    $smarty->assign("crArray",$crArray);
    $smarty->assign("finalAmount",$finalAmount);
    $smarty->assign("finalKg",$finalKg);
    $smarty->assign("partyId",$partyId);
    $smarty->assign("clientDetail",$clientDetail);
    $smarty->assign("clientArray",$clientArray);
    $smarty->display("clientList.tpl");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please reduce the code you posted to the relevant bits. Such a "wall of code" is very hard to work through, especially since you posted it without any explanation...

Comment: Me reduce my code @arkascha

Comment: Looks like you overwrite `$clientRow` withing the iteration of the outer while loop: _both_ calls to `mysql_fetch_array()` assign their result to _the same_ variable.